# Prisma DB Can't connect to AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, next.js, amazon-rds, prisma

I have a nextjs project that's using prismaDB for the ORM. I'm able to connect just fine to my local postgres db but I'm getting this error when running `npx prisma migrate`.

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `db-name.*.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com`:`5432`.

schema.prisma:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  //url    = "postgresql://master_username:master_password@aws_host:5432/db_name"
}
```

The RDS db is currently public and I'm positive that I've copied over the RDS credentials correctly. There doesn't seem to be anything I should be including for the connection to work but I'm not getting any other info as to why I can't reach the db server.

Comment: Is that all there is to the error message?  I should think there would be more lines with more info.  If not, then try to use that same connection string with a tool which generates competent error messages, like `psql`.

Comment: I'm trying to use the db tool in webstorm but it shows pretty much the same error. "The connection attempt failed". I noticed that in RDS if you don't specify the db name in "other configurations" then RDS won't create the db. I deleted the old one and recreated another with a db name but still couldn't connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to replace `db-name.*.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com` with the name of your actual database, unless you replaced it for the purpose of asking this question. Specifically the part where it says `db-name.*`.

Docs: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/error-reference#common

`P1001` indicates that it couldn't find the database given the connection string, NOT necessarily that the credentials you provided were wrong. Make sure you're specifying the correct database name/host and whatever else you need to make it work for AWS.

Comment: Correct. I redacted those values but the string was along the lines of `postgresql://postgres:PASSWORD@DB_INSTANCE.AWS_RDS_HOST:5432/DB_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I was able to connect to RDS after deleting and creating a new DB for the third time. I confirmed connection through pgAdmin then tried it again my app deployed to vercel.

Answer (score 0):

First your Db_url pattern is correct and your database instance is also running and it is public.
There is only problem in the connection, so we need to make sure that aws instance has open ports and firewall is not blocking inbound connection.
So, we need to configure the security group.
[image]

Then click on the security group id and click on edit inbound rules
Here you need to add two more rules.
[image]

0.0.0.0/0 or ::/0 allow all IP addresses to access your instance.